# what's the difference between Map.Entry and map.get(key)

Tags: java

I have a concern about which method is better, `Map.Entry` or `map.get(key)`, the structure of rows is List< Map< String, Object>> the code below as:

```
for (Map<String, Object> row : rows) {
    Object stock = row.get("stock");
}
```

the other:

```
for (Map<String, Object> row : rows) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> cell : row.entrySet()) {
        if (cell.getKey().equals("stock")) {
            Object stock = cell.getValue();
        }
    }
}
```

Which one is better?

and there is another question I curious about, I have only known some key names but not all, I want to get all the values from the map, how should I do?  btw, I don't wanna use entrySet iterator method.

```
for (Map<String, Object> row : rows) {
   Object stock = row.get("stock");
  Object itemId = row.get("itemid");
  Object modelId = row.get("modelid");

   // todo
  // how to get other values that I don't know the key name String}
```

Comment: Those two aren't equivalent - in the first you're iterating over `rows`; in the second you're iterating over `row`.

Comment: @Eran: Yes, quite possibly. The question should be written more clearly though.

Comment: sorry, there are some mistakes took, I had edited it

Comment: btw, there is another problem anyone have some ideas? I have added it to my post question

Comment: Please do not ask multiple questions in the same post. Ask a new question, and make sure it's clear - you say you don't want to use `entrySet` to get all the entries, but that's the most obvious way of doing it - so *why* don't you want to use `entrySet`. (Don't answer here - make sure you specify it in the new question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> which one is better?

Typically, in programming, there is no *universal better*. Things always depend on context.

Having said that, when writing code, you strive to "do what needs to be done" with the least amount of code (that is easy to read and understand).

From that point of view, your first option is the clear winner. It gets the job done, is easier to read and maintain (mainly because you look at less code). Where the job is: iterate over all entries in the map, and do something with each value.

From a "semantical" point of view, the two options "do the same thing", so they are mostly equivalent, I really can't think of an example where you end up with different behavior for the two options (except the different *cost* at runtime, see that other answer).

Comment: While the output of both snippets is the same, I wouldn't call them equivalent, since the first takes constant time and the second takes linear time. If the `Map` is large, the difference in the running times could be significant.

Comment: @Eran Valid point. And glad you put it in your answer, so I can upvote there ;-)

Comment: actually, there is another problem I have added it to my post question, do u have any ideas?

Comment: @ZhangXin Please be careful about turning your question into a moving goal post. You ask a question, you get answers. Coming then back and changing the question to ask "more things" isnt appreciated practice here. Having said that: *// how to get other values that I don't know the key name String* ... we can't tell you that. We dont understand what exactly you intend to do, what your requirements are, and so on. Without that information, nobody can seriously tell you how to solve that problem (that we dont understand, because lack of context)

Comment: @ZhangXin Sure you can just go and call valueSet() on that inner map, and then you got access to all the values. Or well, then you maybe use your second option. Because *then* you need all keys from your inner maps.

Comment: understood, will put it in my answer and post another new question

Answer (score 3):

The first snippet is better, since you seem to need just the value of a single key.

using `row.get("stock")` will take constant (`O(1)`) expected time.

Iterating over the `entrySet` and comparing the key of each `Map.Entry` to the required key, on the other hand, will take linear (`O(n)`) time, which is much worse than the first snippet when the `Map` is large.

You should only iterate over the entire `entrySet` if you need to process all the entries of the `Map`.

Comment: actually, there is another problem I have added it to my post question, do u have any ideas?

Comment: @ZhangXin if you want to get all the values from the Map, and you don't know the keys, use `row.values()` to get a `Collection` of all the values.

Comment: but I don't wanna get all values together, I would like to handle the values that I have known the key and those I haven't known the keys respectively

Comment: @ZhangXin I don't know what you are trying to achieve. If you need to process all the values, but you still want to know the key of each value (so that you'll know which values belong to one of the "known" keys), you'll have to iterate over `entrySet()`. This way, you get all the keys and their corresponding values.